# error on " os.walk('/Users/USERNAME/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary') "

Tags: python

im trying to find all of my file on my mac

```
def findFile(c):
    print(c)
    ls = next(os.walk(c))
    # files = ls[2] if len(ls) > 2 else []
    print(ls)
    if len(ls) > 1:
        dirs = ls[1]
        for i in dirs:
            findFile(c+'/'+i)
    return ""

rootDir = "//Users"
findFile(rootDir)
```

but when it is trying to open /Users/USERNAME/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary it shows an error

```
File "main.py", line 36, in findFile
    ls = next(os.walk(c))
```

when i check the file it was a .photoslibrary, but why does it identified as a folder, anyone know how i solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your code, and the file type (at least in windows os) .photoslibrary, doesn't seem to be the problem. I would love to see the error message. I have seen before where .photoslibrary files are PermissionErrors. I have done some research and found out that iCloud locks these photos unless manually authorized, so I predict that your code is unable to open this file. This may be impossible due to MacOS's requirement. This may not be and seems unlikely considering os.walk() doesn't open your files, but it is a possibility. You could hypothetically add an exception like...

```
if i.endswith(".photoslibrary"):
   pass
else:
   ls = next(os.walk(c))
```

However, if these files are incredibly necessary, I'm not sure how you would force it. I am sincerely sorry if this was of no help!

Comment: thanks for your answer, i solved my problem already, i did " if '.' not in i: "